# output belongs_and_has_many value in show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have the following code but can't render color as expected. When I render item.color I get `#<Color:0x007ffce487a648>`for example. If I render `item.color.map(&:name)` I get `undefined method map for #<Color:0x007ffce6616918>`

```
<% @this_week_orders.each do |order| %>
  <tr style="font-weight:bold;">
    <td><%= link_to "Order #{order.id}", order_path(order) %></td>
    <td><%= l order.date, :format => :long %></td>
    <td><%= pluralize(order.items.count, "item") %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(order.total_price) %></td>
  <tr>
    <% for item in order.items %>
    <tr>
      <td><li><%= item.product.name %></li></td>
      <td><%= item.color %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

- Order `has_many :items`
- Item `belongs_to :order`
- Item `belongs_to :product`
- Item `belongs_to :color`

  ```
  scope :this_week, lambda { where("date > ?", 7.days.ago) }
  ```

Order controller

```
def this_week
@this_week_orders = Order.this_week.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
  end
end
```

Comment: is it a has_many_and_belongs_to relationship? in that case you should do item.colors (mind the plural). this give a array of all the colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#<Color:0x007ffce487a648>` reperesents an object of class `Color` (not a collection of color objects, whereupon it would make sense to use `map`). If `Color` has a `name` attribute, just write `<%= item.color.name %>`.

Comment: Thanks for the explication however I tried with item.color.name but I receive `undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: That means that `item.color` is `nil`, i.e. it doesn't have an associated `Color` object. Check to make sure `item` is what you expect it to be.

Comment: If I run `item.color.inspect` I get `#<Color id: 1, name: "Red", hex_code: "#FF0000", created_at: "2011-10-13 19:41:44", updated_at: "2011-10-13 19:41:44">` so the color is associated, right? Any idea why it doesn't show then?

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense. If `item.color.inspect` returns that, then `item.color` executed in the same place should not be `nil`, and `item.color.name` executed in the same place should return `"Red"`.

Answer (score 1):

`map` is for use on an Array. `item.color` only returns one object. Use:

```
<%= item.color.name %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explication however I tried with item.color.name but I receive `undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 1):

if Color is a class like it appears to be you need to set the color value:

Something like:

```
<%= item.color.name %>
```

or whatever your value for the color is.

Comment: Thanks for the explication however I tried with item.color.name but I receive `undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: did not know about the inspect command. It shows progress '#<Color id: 1, name: "Red", hex_code: "#FF0000", created_at: "2011-10-13 19:41:44", updated_at: "2011-10-13 19:41:44">'

Comment: Then you want `item.color.name`

Comment: It keeps driving me nuts because it returns `undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass`with `item.color.name`

Comment: So when you do item.color.inspect does it show that #<Color... for each line you have?  If not it is because you don't have a color associated with that item.  Try this `item.color.name if item.color`